# Where to override the design of jQuery UI elements?

Tags: anti-patterns, ui

We are using a few jQuery UI elements in our web application, and I need to change their design. For example, the `ui-progressbar` is way too high and its rounded corners don't fit well with our design.

But the style of these jQuery elements is not set in a stylesheet, it appears in `<style>` tags in the element itself. I see two options to override it:

1. Change it in my stylesheet, and litter the style with `!important` statements
2. Go into the jQuery library, and change it right where it's assigned.

We are delivering the library ourselves, not linking to an externally hosted one, so option 2 will work.

But both approaches smell of an antipattern. Which one is the lesser evil, or is there a third one I haven't thought of?